# Javascript - Hidden maths answer.

Tags: javascript, html

The script below generates random numbers, and calculates the answer.

The next thing is that I want to have the answer HIDDEN and place a text area there. Then you have to input an answer and when the answer is correct, it should make the answer green.

I know it is possible, but I've searched on the internet for it without success, so I'm creating a question instead.

Here's the script:

```
<div id="breuken"></div>

$(function () {
    var number = document.getElementById("breuken");
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        var sRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        var fRandom = Math.floor(sRandom + Math.random() * (10 - sRandom));
        var calc = Math.abs(fRandom - sRandom);
        number.innerHTML += "" + fRandom + " - " + sRandom + " = " + calc + "<br />";
    }
    number.innerHTML;
});
```

Comment: Nah, not homework, just want to learn.

Comment: Your question makes very little sense .... try expanding with an example of what you are acutally trying to do !

Comment: Done that, I hope you get it now.

Comment: Is the var `calc` the answer which needs to be replaced by an input? Which framework are you using, `jQuery`?

Comment: You are using `$`, is it jQuery?

Comment: It is, but i already have the answer thanks anyways:)

Comment: @RinkeDoeser If you have `jQuery`at your disposal you should use it! If you have a correct answer please mark so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers does practically the same as @gillesc's but uses `jQuery` to do the heavy lifting, which you should use if you have it at hand. (and is shorter)

Javascript code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XDzS8/)

```
$(function() {
    var checkAnswer = function(elem) {
        if ($(elem).data('calc') == $(elem).val()) {
            $(elem).css('background-color', 'green');
        } else {
            $(elem).css('background-color', 'white');
        }
    };
    var div = $('#breuken');

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var sRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        var fRandom = Math.floor(sRandom + Math.random() * (10 - sRandom));
        var calc = Math.abs(fRandom - sRandom);

        var qa = $('<span>' + fRandom + ' - ' + sRandom + 
            ' = <input type="text"></span><br />');
        qa.find('input').change(function() {
            checkAnswer(this);
        }).data('calc', calc);
       div.append(qa);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/r4QTQ/

It does basic green color change but should be enough for you to modify and do exactly what you want.

Comment: Wow gillesc, Thats awesome, Thank you, Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Created this jQuery **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AtxGz/)** that might help you in the right direction, if you´re using jQuery.

```
var $questions = $('<div />').attr('id', 'questions');
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {

    var question = "Question " + i + "?";
    var answer = i;

    $questions.append(
        $('<div />')
            .attr('id', 'question' + i)
            .addClass('question')
            .append(
                $('<span />').text(question)
            )
            .append(
                $('<input type="text" />')
                    .addClass('answer')
                    .data('answer', answer)
            )
    );
}
$('#container').empty().append($questions);
```

Hope it helps!